# StackExchange.Redis SetScan returns all set members

Tags: redis, stackexchange.redis, nosql

In a simple test I have a set with 10k elements. I noticed that on the first `SetScan` call with 0 cursor it returns whole set and next cursor that will return a number of elements and another cursor which then yields exactly the same result and cursor.

Code below will run in the infinite loop

```
var cursor = 0L;

do
{
    var result = redis.SetScan("key", cursor: cursor, pageSize: 100);

    set.AddRange(result);

    cursor = ((IScanningCursor)result).Cursor;

} while (cursor > 0);
```

Varying page size doesn't have an effect.

Answer (score 2):

SetScan internally handles the cursor if you iterate over the result. PageSize in this context is what SetScan passes as count to SETSCAN when a new page is needed. You don't need to handle the cursor logic yourself. Just iterate over the enumerable:

```
foreach(var redisValue in redis.SetScan("key")
{
    set.Add(redisValue);
}
```

The cursor is exposed for if you need to stop the enumeration in the middle and continue somewhere else out of band.

Comment: that's ok. but I still don't understand why my example code doesn't work correctly. is something wrong with code provided?

Comment: If the cursor returned is the same as the cursor passed in, then the SetScan is done. You don't need the loop because the first call will always return all the elements since you don't limit the iterator on result. set.AddRange(result); will cause the iterator (result) to make all the Redis calls necessary to get the entire set.